# Como resolver codificação errada na exportação de planilhas xml

Tags: php, mysql, codificação-de-caracteres, utf-8

Eu tenho um formulário que recebe alguns de cadastro e são transmitidos para uma outra página via ajax que faz a inserção no banco de dados. O problema é que na hora de receber, se eu não usar o utf8-decode sobre a variável onde tiver acento vai perder formatação dentro do banco de dados.
Até aí tudo bem, o problema mesmo começa na hora de exportar esses dados pelo phpmyadmin. Sempre que tento exportar ele perde a formatação e não encontrei nenhuma combinação que funcione.

Answer (score 1):

Solução.
A solução encontrada foi decodificar tudo usando o UTF8-decode quando for inserir os dados para o banco e na hora de exportar escolher iso-8859-1 para padrão de dados.